# AWS S3 403(Forbidden) Error in angular App during file Upload

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

For my project, I have a requirement to upload pdf into the s3 bucket. So using a lambda function I create a pre-signed URL and using the url i use  http post request to upload the file.

Now, with the pre-signed link i received from the lambda function, it is possible to upload the file using POSTMAN without any, but in my angular Application, for some reason i get a 403(Forbidden) Error.

Here are all my code:

**Lambda Function**

```
async function getSignedUrlForResume(fileName){
    const urlExpiryDuration = 5; //minutes
    console.log("inside get signed Url");
    const key = "Resume/"+fileName;
    var response = "";
    const s3Params ={ 
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: key,
      Expires: urlExpiryDuration*60,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: "application/pdf"
    };
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    try {
      const signedUrl =  await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);
      response = {signedUrl: signedUrl};
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      response = error;
      return response;
    }
}
```

**Component.ts File:**

```
async addResume(){
    let signedUrl : string =  null;

    let fileName: string = this.candidateService.candidateRecords['records'][this.candidateService.indexOfCandidate]['candidate_id']
    +"_"+
    this.candidateService.candidateRecords['records'][this.candidateService.indexOfCandidate]['first_name']
    +"_"+
    this.candidateService.candidateRecords['records'][this.candidateService.indexOfCandidate]['last_name'];
    console.log("File Name: " +fileName);

    this.file = event[0];

    await this.candidateService.getSignedUrl(fileName).then(
      (response: []) => {
        signedUrl = response['signedUrl'];
      }
    );
    console.log(signedUrl);
    console.log(this.file)
    await this.candidateService.uploadResume(signedUrl, this.file).then
    (data => {
      console.log("Upload Response:" +data);
    }).catch((err: Error) => {
      console.log('Error: '+ err);
    });
  }
```

**Component Service**

```
getSignedUrl(fileName: string){
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    queryParams = queryParams.set('fileName', fileName).set('funcName', 'getSignedUrlForResume');
    return this.http.get(AppConstants._API_END_URL, {params: queryParams})
      .pipe(
        retryAfterDelay(this.delayDuration),
        catchError((errorResponse:Error) => {
          return throwError(errorResponse.message);
        }
      )
    ).toPromise();
  }

  uploadResume(signedUrl: string, file: File){
    // Delay not added for upload to s3. since no RDS is used
    return this.http.put(signedUrl, file, {headers: {'Content-Type': file.type}}).toPromise();
  }
}
```

**HTML part:**

```
<input hidden type="file" #fileInput (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)" accept="application/pdf">
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**ERROR:**

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message><HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-security-token</HeadersNotSigned><RequestId>E841149CC447C62D</RequestId></Error>"
```

**Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong here or not done to make this work ??**

Comment: using S3  directly from angular app  is not recommended approach, if I am not wrong.

Comment: just using the url and http post request to upload the file