# Angular - Upload file to S3 using Presigned url

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, pre-signed-url

I need to upload files to S3 from frontend(Angular) using presigned url. I create links to uploading files on the server and return them to the frontend. I am using a put request to upload the file, but I get an error. Although when executing the same request in Postman everything works fine

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/my-test-s3-bucket/a9da491a-cfaa-4532-bae6-43a515f5e657.doc?AWSAccessKeyId=DO00CPCLULU4MB9RHW2A&Content-Type=application%2Fmsword&Expires=1704439698&Signature=GT1PLU6sCqCeLe9nnb5GExs%2BWj4%3D' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

```
  async upload(links: Sections<string[]>, files: Sections<File[]>) {
    const h = (file: File) => ({ 'Content-Type': file.type });
    console.log("links: ", links);
    console.log("files: ", files);

    return await Promise.all([
      ...files.information.map((file, i) =>
        this.http.put(links.information[i], file, { headers: h(file) }).toPromise()
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

CORS config on my bucket:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:4200</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62700027/angular-aws-s3-upload-file-to-aws-s3-using-presigned-url?

Comment: @Peca021 Unfortunately no